# How is type inferred in this snippet?

Tags: haskell, monads, aeson

I'm working through Artyom's Aeson tutorial, and have coded myself this snippet:

```
parseFoo (Object obj) = do
    a <- case HM.lookup "a" obj of
        Just x  -> parseJSON x
        Nothing -> fail "no field 'a'"

    return a
```

I've noticed that if I `return True`, I get an "ambiguous reference" error:

```
No instance for (FromJSON t0) arising from a use of ‘parseJSON’
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
...
```

The type of the non-ambiguous case is

```
parseFoo :: FromJSON b => Value -> Parser b
```

My question is, why (how) does `a` need the `return` statement to infer its type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `parseJSON` is `FromJSON a => Value -> Parser a`, so if you never use the result, GHC can’t possibly figure out what `a` is supposed to be: it could be anything at all with a `FromJSON` instance. When you use it as the return value, then the caller of the `parseFoo` function will pick a concrete type for `b`, which will be used to pick the instance for the `parseFoo` call.

As an aside, your `return` is totally redundant in this case. You could omit the `do`, the `a <-`, and the `return`, since `a >>= return` is just `a` by the monad laws.